# ID3D11Device::CreateTexture3D E_OUTOFMEMORY for 4GB+ textures on 16GB NVIDIA Quadro P5000

Tags: nvidia, direct3d

[ID3D11Device::CreateTexture3D](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11/nf-d3d11-id3d11device-createtexture3d) works fine for textures smaller than 4 GB, but fails with `E_OUTOFMEMORY` for larger sizes, even when there is more memory available. Why?

For example on a NVIDIA Quadro P5000 with 16 GB video memory:

- [DedicatedVideoMemory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dxgi/ns-dxgi-dxgi_adapter_desc) is 16 GB.
- [MaxVolumeExtent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d11/overviews-direct3d-11-devices-downlevel-intro) is 2048.
- So I would expect to be able to create a texture with Width=2000, Height=2000, Depth=2000, Format=`DXGI_FORMAT_R16_UINT` (~15 GiB) but it fails.
- Width=1024, Height=1024, Depth=2048, Format=`DXGI_FORMAT_R16_UINT` (4 GB) still fails.
- Width=1024, Height=1024, Depth=1024, Format=`DXGI_FORMAT_R16_UINT` (2 GB) works.

Other NVIDIA cards (like an NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1070 with 8 GB video memory) have the same limitation.

Is this a known limitation of D3D11? Of NVIDIA drivers / cards? Are there any options to make it work?

```
        ID3D11Texture3D* texture = 0;
        D3D11_TEXTURE3D_DESC texureDesc;
        ZeroMemory(&volTexDesc, sizeof(texureDesc));
        texureDesc.Width = 1024;
        texureDesc.Height = 1024;
        texureDesc.Depth = 2048;
        texureDesc.MipLevels = 1;
        texureDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R16_UINT;
        texureDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
        texureDesc.BindFlags = 0;
        texureDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
        texureDesc.MiscFlags = 0;
        HRESULT result = d3dDevice->CreateTexture3D(&texureDesc, NULL, &texture);
```

(In 64-bit OS / x64 target with 64 GB system memory, nothing else is running and using up system or video memory.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Direct3D 11 specification only requires drivers to support resources sizes up to:

```
min(max(128,0.25f * (amount of dedicated VRAM)), 2048) MB
```

As defined by these constants in the d3d11.h header:

```
D3D11_REQ_RESOURCE_SIZE_IN_MEGABYTES_EXPRESSION_A_TERM (128)
D3D11_REQ_RESOURCE_SIZE_IN_MEGABYTES_EXPRESSION_B_TERM (0.25f)
D3D11_REQ_RESOURCE_SIZE_IN_MEGABYTES_EXPRESSION_C_TERM (2048)
```

As such, generally 2 GB is as large as you can reasonably expect to work for a single resource. Using the x64 version of the OS and Direct3D simply allows you to use many large resources.

See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d11/overviews-direct3d-11-resources-limits) and [Direct3D Specs](https://microsoft.github.io/DirectX-Specs/).

> The same is true of Direct3D 12 in terms of required resource size support.

Comment: Does Direct3D 12 still have the same limits? Is the driver allowed (but not required) to support larger resources? Testing suggests in practice ~4064 MB is the limit of what works on these NVIDIA drivers. Do other graphics cards support even larger (than that / than required) sizes? What are the best techniques for working with such large 3D datasets?

Comment: Have you looked at [tiled resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d11/tiled-resources)?

Comment: I was not aware of them. ["Texture3D might be supported in the future"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d11/tiled-resource-creation-parameters) Is this still in the future?

Comment: It's in Direct3D 12, see [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d12/volume-tiled-resources)

Comment: How large can a tile pool be? Is it still restricted like a single resource? A tiled resource can be _virtually_ larger, but can only reference tiles from one single backing pool of tiles, right? If that pool of tiles is limited in size, there can still not be more than 2048 MB of data accessed via a tiled resource? [ResizeTilePool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11_2/nf-d3d11_2-id3d11devicecontext2-resizetilepool) has a `UINT64 NewSizeInBytes` parameter, so it can be larger (but the initial `CreateBuffer` `D3D11_BUFFER_DESC` `UINT ByteWidth` can not)?

Comment: You should take a look at [this presentation](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2013/4-063) as well as this [blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/tiledresources11/).